# NGINX sometimes throws connection refused - how to get better performance?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have NGINX running, and periodically it will throw "connection refused" errors.

Most of the time, it runs well and proxies all traffic through to my proxy_pass location.

However, when traffic increases I see "connection refused" errors. I'm also running multiple servers of this, and I have tried increases the number of servers. However, I'm looking specifically at how I get better performance from NGINX.

What can I do to get better performance from my server?

Below is the config that I am using:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  sendfile on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size  128;
  large_client_header_buffers 200 32k;
  proxy_buffers   200 32k;
  keepalive_timeout  10;
  proxy_buffer_size   32k;
  server {
    server_name service.url
    location / {
      proxy_pass https://server.url;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      resolver 8.8.8.8;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you (try to) get the results from: `curl -v https://yourserver`, which show the mentioned error? and add them to this question?  It would make it more clear what the error is

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to reproduce all the time as it's intermittent . Will add soon. I'll update the question to make it clearer that I'm looking for performance advice.

Comment: How do you load-balance traffics between your nginx servers?